# High frequency rf resistors

Tags: resistors, rf, reactance

I need non reactive resistors for use at LF thru HF (100KHz thru 30MHz) for use with radio receiving antennas as terminations. Carbon comp and carbon film work but have their shortcomings in stability and TCR. Thin film resistors have low or no inductance but they are expensive. Wirewound have poor frequency response. What other type resistors are suitable?

Comment: So we can provide more useful answers: Surface-mount, through-hole, or chassis-mount? What sort of power ratings?

Comment: Also, what are your targets for the specs you did mention (stability, TCR, inductance)?

Comment: If the power is low <1W, you can get away with large SMD resistors, these are usually thin film but are quite cheap

Comment: More precisely the resistors are used as terminations for outdoor receiving pennant antennas. My focus has been on axial leaded parts and no power is being dissipated. The key performance characteristic is non reactive.

Comment: From resistorguide.com....                                                   Wire wound 0.3 - 56uH                                                     Foil < 0.8uH                                                                      Metal Oxide 3-200 nH                                                       Film <2 nH

Answer (score 4):

For your application I would suggest the use of Metal foil Resistors.A specific foil alloy with known and controllable properties (Ni/Cr with additives) is applied to a special ceramic substrate, resulting in a thermo-mechanic balance of forces. A resistive pattern is then photo-etched in the foil. This process uniquely combines the important characteristics of low TCR, long-term stability, non-inductance, ESD insensitivity, low capacitance, fast thermal stabilization, and low noise in one single resistor technology.

These include low tempco (0.05 ppm/°C ), tolerances as low as ±0.005% (down to ±0.001% when hermetically sealed), load-life stability of ±0.005% (50 ppm) with an  ESD immunity up to 25 kV.

Check the link for more info
 http://www.vishaypg.com/foil-resistors/

Note: 30 MHz is not really considered a high frequency

---

Foil Resistors may be an overkill for your application . They are expensive. Precision thin film resistors may be good enough. Here is a general comparitive table for your reference [image: Resistor Characteristics]

Comment: How would your resistors perform at high values and high voltages   where parasitic capacitance could be an issue ?

Comment: As a note, <30MHz is known as "high frequency (HF)" to amateur radio operators. Ancient terminology, but still what us hams use today.

Answer (score 0):

Foil Resistors may be an overkill for your application . They are expensive. Precision thin film resistors may be good enough. Here is a general comparitive table for your reference [image: Resistor Characteristics]